# Interval between two dates on a state change

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have a `vehicle_states` table like this:

```
 vehicle_id |     state      |          updated_at
------------+----------------+-------------------------------
 ACX-685    | idle           | 2021-12-24 15:13:09.071822+00
 ACX-685    | active         | 2021-12-24 16:03:41+00
 ACX-685    | out-of-service | 2021-12-24 16:15:34.822808+00
 ACX-685    | idle           | 2021-12-24 16:15:35.822808+00
 ACX-685    | active         | 2021-12-24 16:40:23+00
 ACX-685    | idle           | 2021-12-24 16:40:37.436949+00
 ACX-685    | active         | 2021-12-24 16:40:38+00
```

For each vehicle and out-of-service state, I want to find out the time it took to transition out of this state. How much time the vehicle was out-of-service.

I would like to get a table with vehicle_id, timestamp when the vehicle was out-of-service and a third column specifying the interval of time that the vehicle was out-of-service, like so:

```
 vehicle_id |       out_of_service_at       | out_of_service_for
------------+-------------------------------+--------------------
 ACX-685    | 2021-12-24 16:15:34.822808+00 | 00:00:01
 BRT-162    | 2021-12-25 11:26:31.827361+00 | 00:00:27
```

Comment: you are looking to find the time the vehicle spent in "out of service" state?. For clarity sakes, could you share the data for vehicle_id BRT-162

Comment: @GeorgeJoseph yes, that's correct. the BRT-162 example is not real, but the principle is the same the difference between a particular updated_at on a row where state = 'out-of-service' and the elapsed time until a non 'out-of-state' state is seen to the same vehicle (always forward in time). Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve the problem using window functions:

```
with data as (
select 
    *,
    lead(updated_at) over (partition by vehicle_id order by updated_at) next_state
from vehicles
) select 
    *,
    (next_state - updated_at) out_of_service_for
from data where state = 'out-of-service';
```

[PostgreSQL window functions](https://sqlize.online/sql/psql13/c558ef77b4e36e2bff7a7648c9c6d10a/)

Comment: I can't upvote, but I think this is the correct answer. Thank you!